# history - List only successfully run commands

Tags: bash, command-history

I'm wondering if there's a way to use the *history* command but only list commands that were run successfully.  Likewise, would there be a way to list ones that produced errors?

I know each command has an exit status of:

`0` - Successful execution of command
`1` - Command fails because of an error during expansion or redirection, the exit   status is greater than zero.
`2` - Incorrect command usage
`12` - Command found but not executable
`127` - Command not found

and can be checked proceeding the command with `echo $?`
*from:* http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/03/find-exit-status-script-command-linux.html

**Example:**

After running these 4 commands:

```
ls
help
lss
ls nonexistentfile
```

I tried testing to print only successful commands (exit status of 0), which should be only 'ls' and 'help':

```
for j in `history | tail -5 | head -4 | cut -d ' ' -f5-`; do $j > cmd_out; if [[ `echo $?` != 0 ]]; then :; else echo $j | grep -v 'bash'; fi; done; rm cmd_out
```

This outputs:

```
ls
help
bash: lss: command not found
ls
bash: nonexistentfile.txt: command not found
```

This somewhat works, but there are two problems:

1. For some reason, `grep -v 'bash'` is not excluding lines containing 'bash', but if I do `grep 'bash'`, it will include only the lines with 'bash', I'm not sure why one works and not the other.
2. It's separating each line/command by string.  The last `ls` command should be 
    `ls nonexistentfile`, but it's running `ls` and `nonexistentfile` as separate commands.

Any idea on what I should adjust in the command, or how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a hack I used once on a shared account to track who did what:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; sed -i '\$s/\$/ \#$NAME/' $HISTFILE; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

It writes the `history` before the `PROMPT` is displayed: in effect, after each command. You could modify this to use save the exit code in the history:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="CODE=$?; history -a; sed -i '\$s/\$/ \#\$CODE/' $HISTFILE; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This would leave entries in your history like:

```
$ history 2
 1271  vim .bashrc #0
 1272  history 2
```

(The last entry will be updated, *after* the `history` command exits, so the exit code isn't visible in this output.)

This has the annoying effect that history in your prompt will have the comment:

```
$ # press up
$ history 2 #0
```

The comment doesn't affect execution or output usually, but makes editing a pain.

Now you can `grep` your history to see which codes exited successfully:

```
history | grep '#0$'
# or grep '#[^0]*$' for unsuccessful commands.
```

Comment: I tried it on both Mobaxterm and Putty, and got `ls #$CODE, ll #$CODE` for the history output.  I'm not sure if it works for you, but I had to change `sed -i '\$s/\$/ \#\$CODE/' $HISTFILE'` to `sed -i '\$s/\$/ \#$CODE/' $HISTFILE`.  I took the `\` out before $CODE

Comment: @lkisac Oddly for me, it gave `#` (no code) without the escape. Must be some quoting issue.